# how to stop the video and move back to original view in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, media-player

I am playing video in iphone application i want that when done button is clicked player should move back to original view from where it played.

I am using following code

```
  viewDidLoad(){
     [self play];
  }

  -(void)play{
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
    NSURL    *url    = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);  
    [moviePlayer play];
  }
```

Comment: what are u using? storyboard ? or xibs?

Comment: i am playing this on button click when video is playing i want that if user want to move to previous screen from video screen then how to close player

Comment: When you are going back, call this method; [moviePlayer stop]; Ohh I saw your requirement now. sorry;

Comment: where are you exactly playing it? it in the appdidfinishlaunching?

Comment: i am not playing it in appDidfinishlaunching

Comment: where to call this method moviePlayer stop i want that done button which is in player is clicked then this method should call

Answer (score 3):

> You should call this notification:
>
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked) name:**MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification** object:nil];

Try this(I did this for IPad):

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
[self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.player play];
```

and when done button clicked:

```
-(void)doneButtonClicked
{
    [self.player stop];
    [self.player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];//no need this if you are opening the player in same screen;
}
```

Comment: it crasehd application when done button is clicked unrecognised selectro sent

Comment: i am playing this  in the subView

Comment: I think you are opening the moviePlayer in the same screen. I am opening in the different screen. If you opened it in the same screen, remove this statement from (void)doneButtonClicked method: "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; " Check the code I edited now

Comment: That show your internal issue; check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151301/nsinvalidargumentexception-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-using-mpmov

Comment: ok but can you tell me that when i play same this file uploaded to server and from url then it gives the following error An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'

Comment: can you help in this queery which i have stated